# how to enforce sequence in http requests with pipe in Angular 7

Tags: angular, http, sequence, angular7

I have a component that invokes a few http requests to different url's. Each request is implemented as an observable.

```
getIds():Observable<any[]> {
   return this.http
    .post(url1, '')
    .pipe(map(({ Ids}: any) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id }))));
    }

getNames(data: Names):Observable<any[]> {
   return this.http
    .post(url2,element)
    .pipe(map(({ Results }: any) => Results[0].map(item => ({id: item.ID, name: item.CVSS}))));
    }
```

From the component, I need to do,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.Ids = this.getIds();
  Ids.forEach(function(element) 
     this.getNames();
}
```

Can someone please show how I can enforce this order?

Answer (score 2):

Import the switchMap from RXJS

```js
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

then pipe to the map on the returned observable

```js
this.getIds().pipe(
  switchMap((id: string) => this.getNames(id))
).subscribe((response) -> {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`getIds` returns an array of Ids and you want to create an Observable (`getNames`) for each of the Ids. Then, you want to arrange all of the list of names together. There are several ways that you can do this, but I'll suggest one:

```
this.getIds().pipe(
  /*
   * mergeMap here will effectively flatten the inner Observable created by getNames.
   * This means that the next operator will get the *result* of the getNames Observable
   * rather than the Observable itself, so you don't need to subscribe to it explicitly.
   */
  mergeMap(id => this.getNames(id)),

  /*
   * This is optional. `names` is an array. `mergeMap` over an array emits each array element
   * individually. This simply flattens the collection of names arrays.
   */
  mergeMap(names => names),

  /**
   * This is also optional. It will emit the entire collection of results as an array once
   * all of the previous Observables have completed.
   */
  toArray()
)
```

You can subscribe to the Observable created by this to get the flattened list of names.

I would also suggest that, if possible, you add a method to your service that allows you to retrieve all names rather than having to retrieve the list of Ids first and each name per Id individually.

Comment: please bear with me; need a bit more clarity (newbie).
I have the following:

Comment: in, myservice.ts:
    getIds()<any> {
         this.http
            .post(url1, '')
            .subscribe(map(({ Ids }: any) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id, Name: item.Name }))));
        }

    getNames():Observable<any[]> {
         return this.http
            .post(url2, '')
            .pipe(map(({ Names }: any) => Names.map(item => ({Sid: item.Id, Name: item.Name }))));
        }

Comment: in, component.ts:
      getIds(): void {

      this.myservice
         .getIds.pipe(
         mergeMap(id => this.getNames(id)),
         mergeMap(names => names),
         toArray()
         )
      }
and,
     getNames(): void {
       this.myservice
         .getNames(ids)
         .subscribe(val => this.data = val);
      }

Comment: What am I doing wrong here? It doesnt compile saying "Unexpected token" on the last line.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the syntax here. Can you please check? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235705/enforce-order-using-pipe-with-mergemap-in-angular)